# Total number of data points in specific category

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have JSON file and I was checking the total number of data points using this:

```
import json

with open('/..../data.js') as x:
    data = json.load(x)

len(data['ps']['mops']['neos'])
```

and it returned

```
4594
```

Now I want to check the number of data points that contain 'F51' in `['mpcDescription']`

So what I did is:

```
for item in data['ps']['mops']['neos']:
    if 'F51' in item['mpcDescription']:
        len(item['mpcDescription'])
```

But I did not get any results back.
Could some one help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should check `len(item['mpcDescription'].keys())`

Comment: Perhaps you want `len([item for item in data['ps']['mops']['neos'] if 'F51' in item['mpcDescription']])`

Comment: @Nick It worked! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve the result you want with a filtered list comprehension:

```
len([item for item in data['ps']['mops']['neos'] if 'F51' in item['mpcDescription']])
```